# Conditional ui:include vs conditionally rendered include

Tags: jsf

I am wondering which is more effective/readable etc for jsf, conditionally including or deciding inside the include whether to render the content.

e.g. conditional include

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{entitiy.condition}">
    <ui:include src="included.xml">
         <ui:param name="entity" value="#{entity}" />
    </ui:include>
</h:panelGroup>
```

vs always include

```
    <ui:include src="included.xml" />
        <ui:param name="entity" value="#{entity}" />
    </ui:include>
```

and then inside `included.xml`:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{entity.condition}">
    <h:outputText value="#{entity.name}" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO conditional include feels more natural:

```
if condition then
  do something
```

I am not sure if this is really better but use `c:if` for the check as this would totally remove the code evaluation. See [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

`h:panelGroup` adds a span while c:if is pure render logic.

Comment: what about if there are multiple includes after each other and only one is rendered based on the entity type and the whole things is in a DataTable with multiple entities of different types, so for each row a different include is rendered?

from what I read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense
c:if seems like a better option

Comment: Well I am pretty much the only one answering and bringing up the existence of `c:if` and I get `-1` for that ... without any explanation.
This keeps happening lately and it is very annoying.
So please the person with a better answer, write it and teach me.